# Import Python Modules without running .Py

Tags: python-2.7, module

I want to run Module without running:

### main.py:

```
from ex import x
global x

call ex.py

y = x+2
print y
```

### ex.py:

```
x=5*3
```

that is the simplified codes. as you see I call ex.py and use variable x . but when I run main.py , ex.py is running too . but I just want to get what is x and use in main.py

### EDIT:

### main.py:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require20()
import gtk
import subprocess 
from ex import x
global x
```

class Application(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_title("Graphics")
    self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.window.set_border_width(0)    
    self.window.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)


    self.giris=gtk.Label("Fill Up The Required Values Below:")
    self.giris.set_alignment(0.5,0)        

    self.giris1=gtk.Label("Read Values:")
    self.giris1.set_alignment(0.5,0) 

    self.box=gtk.HButtonBox()


    self.entry_a1=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a2=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a3=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a4=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a5=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a6=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a7=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_a8=gtk.Entry()

    self.entry_b1=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b2=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b3=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b4=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b5=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b6=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b7=gtk.Entry()
    self.entry_b8=gtk.Entry() 

    self.label_a1=gtk.Label("X-Label:")
    self.label_a2=gtk.Label("Y-Label:")
    self.label_a3=gtk.Label("Scale:")
    self.label_a4=gtk.Label("XrangePos:")
    self.label_a5=gtk.Label("XrangeNeg:")
    self.label_a6=gtk.Label("YrangePos:")
    self.label_a7=gtk.Label("YrangeNeg:")
    self.label_a8=gtk.Label("Data:")

    self.label_b1=gtk.Label("X-Label:")
    self.label_b2=gtk.Label("Y-Label:")
    self.label_b3=gtk.Label("Scale:")
    self.label_b4=gtk.Label("XrangePos:")
    self.label_b5=gtk.Label("XrangeNeg:")
    self.label_b6=gtk.Label("YrangePos:")
    self.label_b7=gtk.Label("YrangeNeg:")
    self.label_b8=gtk.Label("Data:")

    self.button=gtk.Button("Write")
    self.button.connect("clicked",self.yaz)
    self.button.set_alignment(0.5,0)
    self.button.set_size_request(10,2)


    self.button1=gtk.Button("Read")
    self.button1.connect("clicked",self.oku)
    self.button1.set_alignment(0.5,0)  

    self.button2=gtk.Button("Open")
    self.button2.connect("clicked",self.ac)
    self.button2.set_alignment(0.5,0)

    self.table =gtk.Table(rows=10,columns=4)
    self.table.set_row_spacings(2)
    self.table.set_col_spacings(5)


    self.table.attach(self.giris,0,2,0,1)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a1,0,1,1,2)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a2,0,1,2,3)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a3,0,1,3,4)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a4,0,1,4,5)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a5,0,1,5,6)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a6,0,1,6,7)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a7,0,1,7,8)
    self.table.attach(self.label_a8,0,1,8,9)
    self.table.attach(self.button, 0,2,9,10)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a1,1,2,1,2)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a2,1,2,2,3)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a3,1,2,3,4)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a4,1,2,4,5)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a5,1,2,5,6)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a6,1,2,6,7)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a7,1,2,7,8)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_a8,1,2,8,9)

    self.table.attach(self.giris1,2,4,0,1)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b1,2,3,1,2)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b2,2,3,2,3)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b3,2,3,3,4)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b4,2,3,4,5)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b5,2,3,5,6)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b6,2,3,6,7)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b7,2,3,7,8)
    self.table.attach(self.label_b8,2,3,8,9)
    self.table.attach(self.button2,2,3,9,10)

    self.table.attach(self.entry_b1,3,4,1,2)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b2,3,4,2,3)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b3,3,4,3,4)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b4,3,4,4,5)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b5,3,4,5,6)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b6,3,4,6,7)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b7,3,4,7,8)
    self.table.attach(self.entry_b8,3,4,8,9)
    self.table.attach(self.button1,3,4,9,10)




    self.window.add(self.table)
    self.window.show_all()


def yaz(self,penar):

    yaz_grup =(self.label_a1.get_label(),self.label_a2.get_label(),
               self.label_a3.get_label(),self.label_a4.get_label(),
               self.label_a5.get_label(),self.label_a6.get_label(),
               self.label_a7.get_label(),self.label_a8.get_label())

    yaz_grup1=(self.entry_a1.get_text(),self.entry_a2.get_text(),
                self.entry_a3.get_text(),self.entry_a4.get_text(),
                self.entry_a5.get_text(),self.entry_a6.get_text(),
                self.entry_a7.get_text(),self.entry_a8.get_text())
    f = open("x","w")  

    for k in range(8):
        self.veri = yaz_grup[k]
        self.veri1=yaz_grup1[k]
        f.write(" %s %s \n" %(self.veri,self.veri1))           
    f.close 

def oku(self,penar): 
    x = subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/emeks/workspace/ex/ex.py"])
    print x
```

### ex.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


global x

dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",None,gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                 (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                  gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
dialog.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)



def foo():       

    response = dialog.run()    
    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        dialog.get_filename(), 'selected'
    elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
        print 'Closed, no files selected'
        x =dialog.get_filename()
        print x

if __name__=='__main__':
    foo()
```

dialog.destroy()

Thats whole code and as I said I want to get "X" from ex:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    ex()
```

EDIT : To be more complete on the answer, here is an example.

ex.py :

```
# some lines of code
print ("Hello World")
x=3*5

# A function
def mysum(a,b):
    return a+b

# Protect execution
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ("I am main")
    print ("2 + 2 is %d" % mysum(2,2))
```

"Hello World" will always be printed, but "I am main" will be printed only if ex.py is run directly, not if imported.

`x` is available from the import.

EDIT 2 : With complete ex.py code from the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

global x

def foo():       

    response = dialog.run()    
    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        dialog.get_filename(), 'selected'
    elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
        print 'Closed, no files selected'
        x =dialog.get_filename()
        print x

if __name__=='__main__':

    # dialog related calls shall be protected against execution
    dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",None,gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                 (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                  gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
    dialog.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

    foo()
    dialog.destroy()
```

Comment: The snippet ought to be placed in ex.py. Is it the case ? Maybe your question could be refined by showing a few lines of code.

Comment: no chance for me to know what doesn't work unless you add some more code of ex.py. In particular, I'd need to see what code is executing though you would not expect it.

Comment: UPDATED WİTH REAL CODES

Comment: @nurimuri : please dont shout (don't use capitals). See, I've updated my answer, that's as I told you : your dialog calls were not inside the `if __name__=='__main__':` condition.

Comment: do not offence I used Capitals to be seperate with my code . and thank u for responding